# Как в JavaScript передать значение объекта, а не ссылку на объект?

Tags: javascript, node.js, объекты

Имеется функция (класс) в которую передаю произвольный объект для хранения настроек.

```
    function MyClass(cfg) {
        this._config = cfg;
    }
    MyClass.prototype.cfg = function(key) {
        if (typeof key === 'undefined') return this._config;
        if (typeof this._config[key] === "undefined") return null;
        return this._config[key];
    };

    let config = {
        log_name: "app.new_content.post_source",
        path: [
            {
                url: "/fh/new_content/",
                title: "Новый контент"
            }
        ],
        list_filter_default: {
            trash: 0
        }
    };

    const my_class = new MyClass(config);
    let list_filter_default = my_class.cfg("list_filter_default");

    list_filter_default.trash = 1;

    console.log(my_class);
    //...
    //    list_filter_default: {
    //        trash: 1
    //    }
    //...
```

Как переписать функцию **cfg()**, чтобы дальнейшее изменение переменных не влекло за собой изменение свойства **this._config**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этой ситуации вижу два варианта решения вопроса. 
Примеры будут упрощенны, однако, надеюсь, вы поймете суть

Вариант 1: красивый: заморозка
refer to @Grundy - заморозится **только первый** уровень!

```js
const config = {
  ACCESSS: true
};
function MyClass (cfg) {
  return Object.freeze(cfg);
}

const cfg = MyClass(config);
cfg.ACCESS = false;
cfg.TEST = false;
// nothing changed
console.log(cfg);
console.log(config);
```

Вариант 2: как мы любим

```js
const config = {
  ACCESSS: true
};

function MyClass(cfg) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
}

const cfg = MyClass(config);
cfg.ACCESS = false;
// only parent didn't change
console.log(cfg);
console.log(config);
```

Comment: стоит добавить, что замораживается только первый уровень

Comment: @Grundy  - добавил. И чтоб мы без Вас делали:)

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, так есть и 3 вариант - вернуть новый объект при помощи `Object.assign({},this._config[key])` или спред-оператора `...`. Таким образом исходный объект останется неизменным.

```
function MyClass(cfg) {
        this._config = cfg;
    }
    MyClass.prototype.cfg = function(key) {
        if (typeof key === 'undefined') return this._config;
        if (typeof this._config[key] === "undefined") return null;
        return Object.assign({},this._config[key]);
    };

    let config = {
        log_name: "app.new_content.post_source",
        path: [
            {
                url: "/fh/new_content/",
                title: "Новый контент"
            }
        ],
        list_filter_default: {
            trash: 0
        }
    };

    const my_class = new MyClass(config);
    let list_filter_default = my_class.cfg("list_filter_default");

    list_filter_default.trash = 1;

    console.log(my_class);
//...
//    list_filter_default: {
//        trash: 0
//    }

    console.log(list_filter_default);

//   { trash: 1 }
```

Comment: Чем принципиально ваш вариант отличается от второго моего?)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, копирует только первый уровень, как и твой первый вариант :)

Comment: @Grundy на английском so вроде видел мнение, что копирование через `json` работает быстрее `assign`. Можешь подтвердить/опровергнуть?) Или предложить как проверить:)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, все зависит от браузера и самого объекта. В некоторых случаях JSON не применим в принципе, например, для объектов с циклическими ссылками

Comment: @Grundy, если я задам вопрос - Вы расскажете подробнее?) интересно же:)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, вряд ли. Тут нужны тесты, без них можно только гадать. Но вполне логично было бы, чтобы assign работал быстрее, как минимум за счет копирования одного уровня, в то время как с использованием JSON, сначала должна произойти сериализация объекта, а затем десериализация. Но во что преобразует данный код оптимизатор, сможет сказать только разработчик :-)